# Showing two partitions to be equal

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

I was posed with the following problem " Let $F(n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ with every part appearing at least twice and $G(n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ into parts larger than 1 such that no two parts are consecutive integers. Use conjugate partitions to prove that $F(n)=G(n).$"

What i have so far:

I realize that for G(n), the statement that no two parts are consecutive implies that distance between two is at least two, which gives a similarity with F(n). I think using ferrer diagrams will help a bit, but i could not see how to get started. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Ferrers diagram for $n=6$.

[image: Ferrer diagram]

> I realize that for $G(n)$, the statement that no two parts are consecutive implies that distance between two is at least two,

This might be causing a problem. No two parts are consecutive implies the difference between two parts is not $1$ instead of at least two as you have stated.

Comment: So, what you are suggesting is that that they might even be equal?

Comment: That's correct. And you can see from my Ferrer diagram that $3+3$ in the $F(n)$ count is the same as $2+2+2$ in the $G(n)$ count.

Comment: So, how do i prove that F(n) and G(n) are always equal?

Comment: Try something along this line: given a Ferrer diagram of a partition in $F(n)$, the conjugate is in $G(n)$. It should be fairly straight forward using the property that each row is shows up at least twice due to $F(n)$ property, the conjugate will never have consecutive parts and will never be $1$.

Comment: Cann you elaborate a bit on this "the conjugate will never have consecutive parts and will never be 1."

Comment: Try to draw the Ferrer diagrams for $F(n)$ for a different $n$ (say 8). And see what happens when you do the conjugate partition.