# Number of partitions of a number into distinct parts.

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Let $\pi$ be the partition of $n=a_1+a_2+...+a_r$, where $a_1\geq a_2 \geq ....\geq a_r\gt0$. Prove that number of partition $\pi$ of $n$ with $a_r=1$ and $a_j-a_{j+1}$ = 0 or 1 for $1\leq j\leq r-1$ equals $p^d (n)$, i.e the number of partitions of n into distinct parts.

What i have so Far:

I can see that since $a_r=1$ and $a_j-a_{j+1}$=0 or 1 so putting j = r-1 we have $a_{r-1}=1$. Similarly all $a_j$ must be 1.This implies that no two $a_j$ are equal. Please help

Comment: This sounds very similar to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121442/showing-two-partitions-to-be-equal)? Perhaps we/you should first solve the other one before posting new ones immediately.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Any help on either of them would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set 
$$\epsilon_j=a_j-a_{j+1} \quad \text{ for } \quad  1\leq j\leq r-1.$$ 
Then we have
$$ a_{r-j}=1+\epsilon_{r-1}+\cdots +\epsilon_{r-j} \quad \text{ for } \quad  1\leq j\leq r-1,$$ 
so 
$$ n=r+(r-1)\epsilon_{r-1}+ (r-2)\epsilon_{r-2}+\cdots +2\epsilon_2+\epsilon_1 $$
defines a partition of $n$ with all distinct parts (ignoring the summands with $\epsilon_j=0$) and highest part being $r$. 
The correspondence thus defined is bijective: follow the same steps in reverse order.

Comment: can you please point out if there is any mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on the equivalence of data you mentioned?

Comment: I do not understand it: $a_r=1$ and $a_{r-1}-a_r=a_{r-1}-1=0$ or $1$ only implies $a_{r-1}=1$ or $2$.

Comment: OOH...that was a mistake, thanks. Can you elaborate on the last line of your proof?

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify.